# Ideomatic store subscription in redux-observable

Tags: redux-observable

What is the ideomatic way in redux-observable to handle store [subscription](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener)?
As the store only changes due to actions, is it reasonable to create an epic that will watch only the store for changes?

```
export const onChangeDoSomething: Epic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    map(([_, state]) => state.some.key.to.watch),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    mapTo(MyActions.doSomething())
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your epic can simply subscribe to the state observable. Adapting your example, something like this:

```
export const onChangeDoSomething: Epic = (action$, state$) =>
  state$.pipe(
    map(state => state.some.key.to.watch),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    mapTo(MyActions.doSomething()),
  )
```